# .htaccess two different rules but only one per time

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rather new to the whole .htaccess thing and I'm using the following right now to use 'pretty url's':

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now i found my website a bit slow and decided to start gzipping my CSS files thru a php script I found somewhere on the web ([the website](http://www.wangarific.com/how-to-gzip-css-files/)). For this to work I need to rewrite the url to open the correct php file. That would look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
```

But I only want the first to happen when the second doesn't and vice versa. In other words i'd like something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    if request doesn't contain .css do
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
    else do
        RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me with the proper code or a place where i can find a way to use some kind of conditional statement in htaccess files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will go onto something like that.

First you define a new condition ([RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)) then you apply this condition using a rule ([RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)).

Thanks to the [flag `L`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) at the end of the RewriteRule, this *stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules*. So when the request is a `.css` file, the first rule will be apply and not the second one. For all others request, it won't match the first condition, then go to the second one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.css$
    RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "First you define a new condition (RewriteCond)..." - actually, the new _condition_ here is entirely superfluous. The important part is the order of the directives (and the `L` flag).

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this, use Apache deflate module to Gzip you files. This is what I use in .htaccess :

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/php text/html text/txt text/javascript text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Check out the documentation to have more info on the mime type and the syntax : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: _Why_ should you not compress the files the way the OP has done?

Comment: Putting an additional RewriteRule in the htaccess and using a PHP script to compress in gzip, when an Apache module exists. Just simpler, less potential bugs, more performance... Do I have to say more?